# How can I detect line breaks in string coming from state?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble detecting line breaks coming from a text area. The standard `.replace('↵', '\n')` doesn't work, because by the time I call `this.state.note` the return characters have been respected.

From the console:

`> this.state
{flashMessage: "", note: "one potato ↵two potato↵three potato↵four", showShareModal: false, isEditing: true}`

`> this.state.note
"one potato 
two potato
three potato
four"`

I've attempted to use encoudeURI and searching the string for '\n' - both with no luck.

Is there a way I can get the raw format of `this.state.note`?

Comment: Where does `note` come from? and what is the return character being replaced with?

Comment: When I look in the database after saving a new note, there are no return characters. So I have nothing to replace. My end goal is to pass this note to a `<a href:"mailto:...">` It would be easy if I could detect any kind of return character and replace it with `%0A`. The note is attached to something like `this.props.users` where I am iterating over all users that have an attached note.

Comment: would it be possible to replace returns with `'\n'` when you take the user input before saving it to the database?

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing is happening on save. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my failed attempts.
```changeNote(e) {
    this.setState({
      flashMessage: "",
      note: e.target.value
    });
  }```
from the console if I drill down through the event, I can go `e.target.defaultValue` and see the return characters. But as soon as the state is set, they disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was able to use `encodeURI(this.state.note)`. Because my end goal was to pass this to a `mailto:` link, the encoded return statements get translated perfectly into %0A.

Answer (score 1):

React will replace `'↵'` with `'\n'` automatically so if your textarea is controlled, your component's state should hold the text for the text area with `'\n'` characters included. Sending (POST) and storing the text should not remove `'\n'` characters, so as far as I can tell from the code you have shown, the `'\n'` characters are still present.

I suspect the issue is simply that HTML does not use `'\n'` as its linebreak character, so the new lines are not shown on the page. Instead HTML uses `<br/>`. Better would be to break the `note` into separate `<p>` elements. Here's how you could do that:

```
const splitNote = this.state.note.split('\n').map(e => <p>{ e }</p>);
```

You could also split `note` into `<span>` elements and then put them in a `<div>` with `{display: flex; flex-flow: column;}`. Up to you.

Note:

If, for some reason your `'\n'` characters are being removed somewhere, and there is no reasonable way to stop this, you could replace `'\n'` with `'\\n'` before the replacement happens. But I don't think this is a likely scenario.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this! Unfortunately I still was never able to detect line breaks when attempting to split and parse the string. However, I ended up being able to get away with `encodeURI`.